# How to add a specific key on android keyboard

Tags: android

I've used android:inputType="numberDecimal" on my edittext.

I want to show / key on that keyboard.

for example i want to enter 1/2 instead of 0.5.

is it possible on android?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried searching??

Try looking at [`KeyboardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) and [`Keyboard`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html). Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:digits="0123456789/.-">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you make custom keyboard.